# How should I import data into QuickBooks from my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, quickbooks

I'm working on a Rails project that needs to be able to import/export (mostly import) invoice data to/from QuickBooks. In Googling, the QuickBooks SDK and Web Connector come up often. However, both seem to only be for the Windows desktop versions. This QuickBooks instance is on a Mac.

The import can either be via an API or, if possible, a file could be generated from within the web app that could later be imported manually.

Currently, QuickBooks 2009 is what's being used. However, assume we can use nearly any version of QuickBooks. Online or desktop (Mac).

What would the best route be to get invoice data to/from the Rails application to QuickBooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, QuickBooks for Mac *does not support any real method of integration*. It's definitely the "black sheep" of the Intuit family.

The closest you can get is IIF file imports/exports.

There is detailed information on this (deprecated, and very limited) file format over here:

- http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/HOW12778

You would be so, so, *sooo* much better off moving off of QuickBooks for Mac through, as the APIs for both QuickBooks for Windows (Web Connector/SDK/COM) and QuickBooks Online (REST v3 APIs) are much, much better than IIF imports/exports.

Comment: Thanks! One question: When building an app that uses the QuickBooks Online REST api does the app need to go through the review process regardless of whether or not it's in Intuit app store?

Comment: You only need to go through the review process if you're going to be listed on appcenter.intuit.com. If you don't want to be listed there, no review process is necessary.